Classic film where 3 women live together and trick men out of money
I saw this movie on Turner Classic Movies years ago and I can't remember the name.  It is an old movie from either the 1940'0r the 1950's.  Three women are living in an apartment together. They don't have money to pay their bills so they each date men and trick them out of money. The three women do this often but one by one each of them meet a man who they each fall in love with. It is a what I would call a romantic comedy.

Sounds like How to Marry a Millionaire (1953) with Betty Grable, Marilyn Monroe and Lauren Bacall:

Three New York models move into a Manhattan penthouse apartment and set out to find eligible millionaire bachelors to marry. Two of the women find a potential candidate, but all three also fall in love with other men who may not be as financially secure. Each woman now faces a dilemma: do they choose love or money? 

Here's the trailer from TCM:



